# gfortran optimization breaking code

Tags: compiler-optimization, gfortran

I wrote a ~2300 line fortran program for my research. For a long time, I compiled it with gfortran's -O3 optimization flag. Although it worked well at the time, at some point certain simulations started producing bad results. I finally tracked the problem down to the O3 flag. I've seen advice to avoid using O3, so I'm fine avoiding it.

However, I still have some issues.

While the O0 and O2 optimization settings produce good results, the O1 option causes problems similar to the O3 setting.

When I compile the code with O1, I get a warning that a variable may be uninitialized (-Wmaybe-uninitialized). I'm sure the variable will be initialized. I don't get that warning with O0, O2, or O3; I used -Wall for all of them.

I'm looking for any advice on what to do. Are there any common culprits for this behaviour?

Unfortunately, it's not easy for me to say exactly what's going wrong. (Describing the symptoms in the simulations' results probably wouldn't be useful since it would take some time to explain what the simulation does.) I have only one guess. The code is a monte carlo simulation, so it uses lots of random numbers. Wrongly distributed or correlated "random" numbers could explain the symptoms.

The problem with O1 really concerns me. It's a big speedup over O0, but the problems with O1 make me hesitant to use O2.

The sourcecode is large enough that I don't see an easy way to pinpoint the problem, so I'd like to avoid searching for a needle in that haystack. (Although I've already excluded ~2/3 of the haystack.)

FWIW, I'm using gfortran 4.8.1 under Ubuntu, but gfortran 4.4.6 on Red Hat seems to have similar problems.

---

EDIT: I've tracked the problem down to one bit of code (relevant variable definitions are at the bottom and comments are removed for brevity):

```
if(rnum() <= specP)then
  ph%q(crossingType) = -1.0 * ph%q(crossingType)
else
  theta = dasin(dsqrt(rnum()))
  phi = 2*pi*rnum()

  newDir(crossingType) = dcos(theta)
  if(vel(crossingType) > 0) then
    newDir(crossingType) = -1.0 * newDir(crossingType)
  endif

  select case(crossingType)
    case(1)
      newDir(2) = dsin(theta)*dcos(phi)
      newDir(3) = dsin(theta)*dsin(phi)
    case(2)
      newDir(3) = dsin(theta)*dcos(phi)
      newDir(1) = dsin(theta)*dsin(phi)
    case(3)
      newDir(1) = dsin(theta)*dcos(phi)
      newDir(2) = dsin(theta)*dsin(phi)
    case default
      print *, 'ERROR!'
      read(*,*)
  end select

  ph%q = norm2(ph%q)*newDir
endif
```

If I set `specP` to 1.0, then the first part of the if statement always executes. Everything is fine for both the O0 and O3 optimization settings.

if I set `specP` to 0.0, the second part of the if statement always executes. The simulation works correctly with O0 but fails with O3.

If I replace the whole if statement with `ph%q(crossingType) = -1.0 * ph%q(crossingType)`, then everything works as expected for both the O0 and O3 optimization settings; the problem isn't from `specP` being used elsewhere in the program.

Does anything look fishy with that code?

I've tried various things, but nothing has helped. (E.g. `newDir = 0`. I initially had something shorter instead of the case statement, but I moved to the case statement for brevity.)

Relevant variable definitions:

```
real*8, parameter     :: pi = 3.141592654D0
real*8                :: theta, phi, specP
real*8, dimension(3)  :: newDir
integer               :: crossingType ! has a value of 1, 2, or 3
type(phonon)      :: ph
```

Additionally:

```
type phonon
  real*8, dimension(3) :: q
  blah...
end type phonon
```

and

```
function rnum() !returns a random number in [0,1]
  implicit none
  real*8 :: rnum
  call random_number(rnum)
endfunction
```

Comment: What you write are the typical symptoms of a bug due to accessing uninitialized variables or some memory corruption. Instead of hiding the bug by playing with the optimization flags, I suggest you try to find the bug and fix it. I don't know gfortran but starting from [gcc 4.8, address sanitizer is available](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html). See here [usage](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html). Also, please try to *check* if all variables are indeed initialized, see [compiler options](http://www.fortran-2000.com/ArnaudRecipes/CompilerTricks.html#fComp_Uni) for that.

Comment: Thanks for the info; I'll dig some more.

Comment: I'm compiling it with the following command, but I'm not seeing anything. From looking at the simulation results, I know that the bug should rear its head almostimmediatly. f95 -Wall -Wtabs -ffree-line-length-none -O3 -o pmc -march=native -finit-real=nan -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero -fsanitize=address -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer ...files and libraries

Comment: Adding -finit-integer=0 -finit-logical=false doesn't fix anything either.

Comment: OK, please try these two: `-O0 -finit-real=nan -finit-integer=-1000000 -finit-logical=true -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow -fbounds-check -ftrapv -fno-fast-math -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer` and separately `-O0 -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow -ftrapv -fno-fast-math -fsanitize=address -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer` and compare the results to those good results that you have obtained previously with `-O0` only. The point in `-finit-*` is to set the values obviously wrong. Some of the flags *might* conflict with the new `-fsanitize=address` so I split them into two that hopefully don't conflict.

Comment: Neither identifies nor reproduces the bug. Moving to O1, O2, or O3 is still the only way I've found to reproduce the bug. Let me know if you have any other thoughts.

Comment: I don't have other ideas at the moment, I am sorry. How difficult would it be to compile and run your code on my Linux machine? Without seeing the actual code, it is very hard to guess what's going on. It's not impossible that you stepped on some issue related to compiler optimizations but I still suspect some sort of bug in your code that only becomes visible when you play with the optimization flags. During the week-end, I can look at the code and try to debug it if it is not too difficult to compile and run.

Comment: No worries. I tracked down the bug's location to an if statement, but I haven't been able to fix it. See the edit above. It shouldn't be hard to compile under linux; the only external library it needs is netcdf (libnetcdff5 in the debian repositories). That said, I'd like to avoid wasting your weekend time.

Comment: Now that I see your code: Please try `-fno-fast-math -fmath-errno  -fno-unsafe-math-optimizations -fno-finite-math-only  -frounding-math -fsignaling-nans -fno-cx-limited-range`. Basically, I am just negating all the flags that `-ffast-math` would enable. Chances are, you get different results due to some overly aggressive floating point optimization.

Comment: OK, one more. Please try all the above flags with both `-ffloat-store` and `-fno-float-store`.

Comment: Those flags didn't seem to help when optimization was turned on. It looks like -O1, -O2, and -O3 don't turn on the -ffast-math optimizations, so they were already turned off. FWIW, I tried -ffast-math with -O0, and the simulation still worked.

Comment: From the doc: *"-ffast-math [...] This option should never be turned on by any -O option since it can result in incorrect output [...]"* which is in agreement with your findings. Sorry, it was my mistake.  I am not sure `-ffast-math` has any effect with `-O0` since `-O0` means no optimizations, which, in my opinion, should include `-ffast-math` which in turn would also explain your findings. Have you tried `-ffloat-store` and `-fno-float-store`?

Comment: Yes, I tried both. I decided to start playing with the individual optimization flags to see if I could track down the offending flag. What I found is this: If I use the -O1 option, the code fails, but things work fine if I manually set all the 31 flags that -O1 enables (see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html ). Do you have any idea why that happens?

Comment: Yes, the documentation is most likely incomplete... :( If you share your code (github? sourceforge.net?), I can look at it during the week-end. I will also need some explanation: I must understand how to run it and when are the results OK / not OK.

Comment: I shouldn't release the code publically, but I've put I've temporarily posted it at https://mywebspace.wisc.edu/lnmaurer/web/pmc_source.tar.gz . Let me know when you've downloaded it so that I can take that down. There is a readme file with some directions and some example output in the download. (The latter takes up most of the space in the file.)

Comment: OK, it's here. You can delete the comment here as well so that nobody else can find it. I will also keep your codes private.

Comment: I can only look at it during the week-end and today is Monday, so...

Comment: No worries. The code is working with O0, so while more optimization would be nice, I can live without it. Thanks for offering to take a look!

Comment: Sure. I think you should be able to turn on optimization and I suspect a bug somewhere. Compilers can do nasty things when the optimizations are turned on; maybe it is a bug in the compiler. I am curious...

Comment: I have downloaded the code, thanks. You can delete your comment with the link.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't have time to look into the problem in detail. However, I would worry about those warnings that I get by running `libs/makelibs`. These can be the source of those type of memory corruptions that I was referring to in my very first comment. Unfortunately, I don't do Fortran but I will check what those warnings mean and create some tests to check what can happen if they are ignored. In the meantime: When I run the compile script in the top level directory, I get `Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'netcdf.mod'` and `'ncdf.mod'`.

Comment: If you have the netcdff library installed, there should be a netcdf.mod file; mine is at /usr/include/netcdf.mod. If yours is elsewhere, you probably need to edit the compile script. With regard to the libraries, I have a hard time believing that they're a problem. Kraken and FFTPACK get called once each. QUADPACK gets called more frequently, but it's a very widely used and well tested library that dates to 1981. Ditto for FFTPACK, which is also widely used and dates to 1985.

Comment: I have installed libnetcdff5 and all its dependencies (Ubuntu 12.10) but there is no netcdf.mod file on my hard drive. Double-checked this. As for the warnings, I will nevertheless look into it. Perhaps they are indeed harmless but I would like to check it myself.

Comment: Apparently `netcdf.mod` is in the `libnetcdf-dev` package. (At Least that's what apt-file says.)

Comment: OK, I will look into that, thanks. But not now... :(

Comment: I looked at the warnings that the libraries give and I must say it is sloppy coding on the authors' part (to say the very least) to ignore those warnings. Those warnings do raise red flags that memory corruption is just around the corner. *"Kraken and FFTPACK get called once each. QUADPACK gets called more frequently, but [...]"* The only thing that matters that it gets called at least once. A single memory corruption is more than enough.

Comment: *"[...] well tested library that dates to 1981. Ditto for FFTPACK, which is also widely used and dates to 1985."* I looked at the code where the compiler was complaining: Last changed 2011 according to the comment; any of the recent changes could have introduced a not yet discovered bug. Also note that bugs can hide for decades and only a newer compiler reveals their existence.

Comment: I am not saying that your problem stems from any of those warnings but I would definitely worry about those warnings. It's not your fault that we get these warnings and there is probably not much you can do to fix them (unless you understand that messy code). :( I only have gfortran 4.7 on my machine which doesn't have address sanitizer yet. I have built the latest gfortran form source but I couldn't get everything up and running (libnetcdf). Unfortunately, I don't have more time; I give up. I am sorry I couldn't help.